# decltype(auto) in member function ignores invalid body, decltype(expr) fails

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

I have a simple templated wrapper struct with a member function calling `.error()` on an object of its template type.

```
template <typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    T t;
    decltype(auto) f() {
        return t.error(); // calls .error()
    }
};
```

If I instantiate this with a type that doesn't have an `error()` member function, it's fine as long as I don't call it.  This is the behavior I want.

```
Wrapper<int> w; // no problem here
// w.error(); // uncommented causes compilation failure
```

If I use what I thought was the semantic equivalent with a trailing return type, it errors on the variable declaration

```
template <typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    T t;
    auto f() -> decltype(t.error()) {
        return t.error();
    }
};

Wrapper<int> w; // error here
```

I'll accept that the two are not semantically equivalent, but is there anyway to get the behavior of the former using a trailing return type (C++11 only) without specializing the whole class with some kind of `HasError` tmp trickery?

Comment: @dyp `decltype(auto)` was added in C++14.

Comment: @Brian Ah, I was mislead by the C++14 tag. Should have read more carefully, thanks.

Comment: If `t` is a public data member, why not use a free function (template)?

Comment: @dyp it's private in the real case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between the versions

```
decltype(auto) f();
auto f() -> decltype(t.error());
```

is that the function *declaration* of the second can be invalid. Return type deduction for function templates happens when the *definition* is instantiated <sup>[dcl.spec.auto]/12</sup>. Although I could not find anything about return type deduction for member functions of class templates, I think they behave similarly.

Implicitly instantiating the class template `Wrapper` leads to the instantiation of the *declarations*, but not of the *definitions* of all (non-virtual) member functions <sup>[temp.inst]/1</sup>. The declaration `decltype(auto) f();` has a non-deduced placeholder but is valid. On the other hand, `auto f() -> decltype(t.error());` has an invalid return type for some instantiations.

---

A simple solution in C++11 is to postpone the determination of the return type, e.g. by turning `f` into a function template:

```
template<typename U = T>
auto f() -> decltype( std::declval<U&>().error() );
```

The definition of that function worries me a bit, though:

```
template<typename U = T>
auto f() -> decltype( std::declval<U&>().error() )
{
    return t.error();
}
```

For the specializations of `Wrapper` where `t.error()` is not valid, the above `f` is a function template that cannot produce valid specializations. This could fall under [temp.res]/8, which says that such templates are ill-formed, No Diagnostic Required:

> If no valid specialization can be generated for a template, and that template is not instantiated, the template is ill-formed, no diagnostic
>   required.

However, I suspect that rule has been introduced to *allow*, but not require, implementations to check for errors in non-instantiated templates. In this case, there is no programming error in the *source code*; the error would occur in instantiations of the class template described by the source code. Therefore, I think it should be fine.

---

An alternative solution is to use a fall-back return type to make the function *declaration* well-formed even if the *definition* is not (for all instantiations):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> struct type_is { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    T t;

    template<typename U=T, typename=void>
    struct error_return_type_or_void : type_is<void> {};

    template<typename U>
    struct error_return_type_or_void
        <U, decltype(std::declval<U&>().error(), void())>
    : type_is<decltype(std::declval<U&>().error())> {};

    auto f() -> typename error_return_type_or_void<>::type {
        return t.error();
    }
};
```

Comment: One should probably add some error-checks to make sure that `U == T`, e.g. a `static_assert`.

Comment: I don't think [temp.res]/8 applies in this case, since instantiating the class template specialization only instantiates the declaration of the member function template, so as far as checking is concerned, all you have is the declaration. Having it apply in this case would mean that you check member function templates more stringently than plain member functions, and that using `std::vector<DefaultConstructible>` is ill-formed NDR (the template `insert()`  and `assign()` taking non-forward iters require MoveInsertable/MoveAssignable), which is almost certainly not intended by the committee.

Comment: @t.c. maybe, but intentions don't excuse code not permitted, unless there is no other alternative.  I read that as intending to allow more checks later, but such checks may not error out on a template that coukd (currently) be valid.  So if we end up ensuring a template is always invalid and add diagnostics in a future iteration, we have only broken code that was already ill formed.

Comment: @Yakk The point is that lazy instantiation of member function definitions of class templates is definitely an intended technique, and is used all over the place in the standard library. There's no reason to believe that member function templates are supposed to be treated differently.

Comment: @t.c. except for a clause in the standard that says all function templates must have a valid instantiation.  Maybe it needs an 'except for members of tsmplate types' or 'if a member function template is contained within a template class, there must be some combination of template arguments for the class and function that result in a legal instantiation'.  It would be great if the standard said something like that.  But it doesn't.  :`(  (and neither quote is quite right: we need infinite recursion)

Comment: @Yakk But that clause does not have to be read that way. The standard explicitly says that implicitly instantiating a class template just instantiates the declaration of the member function template, which can sensibly be read as "as far as checking is concerned, the function template `Wrapper<int>::f()` has no definition at all". So all is well as long as the declaration is well-formed.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is a tagged crtp.

```
  // todo:
  template<class T>
  struct has_error; // true_type if T.error() is valid

  template<class D,class T,bool Test=has_error<T>{}>
  struct do_whatever {
    D* self(){return static_cast<D*>(this);}
    D const* self()const{return static_cast<D const*>(this);}

    auto f()->decltype(self()->t.error()) {
      return self()->t.error();
    }
  };
  template<class D,class T>
  struct do_whatever<D,T,false>{};
```

now `f()` just isn't there if `T` has no `error()`.